# How to create a snapshot of an encrypted btrfs @home subvolume?

Tags: filesystem, backup, encryption, btrfs

We are using btrfs for its snapshot capabilities so we can backup user home directories. The user home directories are encrypted with encryptfs. We run

> sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /home/snapshot

Unfortunately there are no files in the `/home/snapshot/<username>` or `/home/snapshot/.encryptfs` directories to backup.

How can I create a readable snapshot? Note we are sshing into the user machines with the user account using keys. So if we ssh manually into the box we can read the user home directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

The default setup of ecryptfs on Ubuntu mounts the user's directory only after successful login (with the key derived from the user's password). If the user is not currently logged on, even root doesn't have access to the unencrypted version of the files.

For encrypted files, check the @.Private@ directories under the `@home` subvolume.